# Is it possible to app.post once for multiple jade file in the same directory using node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am trying to use node.js to create a program that stores a task, each task is dynamic: such as adding two random number, so I store the task as a jade file, since the second time you called, the random number might be different

The problem I am having right now is that I can write the app.post for each task, but I don't want to do that as there might be ten jade files in that directory, and I have to write app.post for each task ten times, which is not scalable, so I was wondering if there is a way to run all the jade file using one app.post?

Any hint would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use `app.get('/:task', do)` for routing and `req.params.task` to get the value passed from client.

See http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params for more information.